# Named Items in XAML don't Exist in Current Context

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I am working on a school project, and I need to have items bound between my XAML and C# code. I have defined the names in the XAML file, but the C# code is reporting that some of the items do "not exist in the current context." The variables in the C# with this error are:

```
StartDatePicker
EndDatePicker
InstructorName
InstructorEmail
InstructorPhone
```

I have replaced these items by copying and pasting the x:Name fields from the XAML file, cleaned all of the files and rebuilt the solution, but am still receiving the error.

**The affected C# code blocks:**

```
public CourseInfoPage(Courses selectedCourse)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            thisCourse = selectedCourse;
            courseId = thisCourse.Id;
            int courseInstructorId = thisCourse.Instructor;
            GetCourseInstructor(courseInstructorId);
            StartDatePicker.Date = thisCourse.RealStartDate;
            EndDatePicker.Date = thisCourse.RealEndDate;
        }
private void GetCourseInstructor(int courseInstructorId)
        {
            using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DBLocation))
            {
                var instructorName = conn.Query<Instructors>($"SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Instructors WHERE Id = {courseInstructorId}");
                var email = conn.Query<Instructors>($"SELECT Email FROM Instructors WHERE Id = {courseInstructorId}");
                var phone = conn.Query<Instructors>($"SELECT Phone FROM Instructors WHERE Id = {courseInstructorId}");

                InstructorName.Text = instructorName.ToString();
                InstructorEmail.Text = email.ToString();
                InstructorPhone.Text = phone.ToString();
            }
        }
```

**The XAML CollectionView:**

```
<CollectionView x:Name="CourseInfoView">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Padding="10">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label Grid.Column="0"
                               Grid.Row="0"
                               Text="{Binding CourseID}"
                        <Label Grid.Column="1"
                               Grid.Row="0"
                               Text="{Binding CourseName}"
                        <Label Grid.Column="0"
                               Grid.Row="1"
                               Text="Start Date:"
                        <DatePicker x:Name="StartDatePicker"
                                    MinimumDate="01/01/2020"
                                    MaximumDate="12/31/2050"
                                    Date="{Binding RealStartDate}"
                                    DateSelected="OnDateSelected"
                                    Grid.Column="1"
                                    Grid.Row="1"
                            <DatePicker.Format>MM/dd/yyyy</DatePicker.Format>
                        </DatePicker>
                        <Label Grid.Column="0"
                               Grid.Row="2"
                               Text="End Date:"
                        <DatePicker x:Name="EndDatePicker"
                                    MinimumDate="02/01/2020"
                                    MaximumDate="01/01/2051"
                                    Date="{Binding RealEndDate}"
                                    DateSelected="OnDateSelected"
                                    Grid.Column="1"
                                    Grid.Row="2"
                            <DatePicker.Format>MM/dd/yyyy</DatePicker.Format>
                        </DatePicker>
                        <Label Grid.Column="0"
                               Grid.Row="3"
                               Text="Select a status:"
                        <Picker x:Name="picker"
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                Grid.Row="3">
                            <Picker.ItemsSource>
                                <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                                    <x:String>Not Started</x:String>
                                    <x:String>In Progress</x:String>
                                    <x:String>Completed</x:String>
                                    <x:String>Not Passed</x:String>
                                </x:Array>
                            </Picker.ItemsSource>
                        </Picker>
                        <Label Grid.Column="0"
                               Grid.Row="4"
                               Text="Course Instructor:"
                        <Label Grid.Column="1"
                               Grid.Row="4"
                               x:Name="InstructorName"
                        <Label Grid.Column="0"
                               Grid.Row="5"
                               Text="Instructor Email:"
                        <Label Grid.Column="1"
                               Grid.Row="5"
                               x:Name="InstructorEmail"
                        <Label Grid.Column="0"
                               Grid.Row="6"
                               Text="Instructor Phone:"
                        <Label Grid.Column="1"
                               Grid.Row="6"
                               x:Name="InstructorPhone"
                        <Label Grid.Column="0"
                               Grid.Row="7"
                               Text="Course Description:"
                        <Label Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                               Grid.Row="8"
                               Text="{Binding CourseDescription}"
                        <Button x:Name="courseNotesButton"
                                Text="View Course Notes"
                                Clicked="courseNotesButton_Clicked"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
```

I'm certain it's something simple that I'm missing, but I can't see what it is. Any help anyone can provide would be super; thanks!

Comment: First of all: your SQL can be better : $"SELECT FirstName, LastName, Email, Phone FROM Instructors WHERE Id = {courseInstructorId}". Add "courseInstructorId" as parameter. It is a bad practice to do it your way (sqlInjection)

Comment: Values that give your errors - bind them as 'RealEndDate ' and everything will work. As I understand you use MVVM pattern, so it's recommended to bind values and do not provide any view information in viewModel

Comment: @Sasha CourseId is not part of the Instructors table, so I'm not sure why I should add that, and the SQL is not causing an issue. I could modify the query to create an object of type Instructor, but that would be more code that is unnecessary for the project.

Comment: I am not using MVVM, as that is an atrocity that I want nothing to do with.

Comment: Where are the methods `CourseInfoPage` and `GetCourseInstructor` are they in the Xaml's code behind file? If yes they should be available. Try saving, cleaning and rebuilding the solution.

Comment: @Nikhileshwar: Yes, the C# code is in the XAML's code behind file. As I stated in my original post, I have already saved, cleaned, and rebuilt the solution without resolving the issue.

Answer (score 3):

You are using a `DataTemplate`, that means the names will not be available in the code-behind. The template is something that is inflated at runtime whenever there is a need. It's impossible to refer to controls like this inside a `DataTemplate`. The template will be repeated for each item in the underlying collection.

You will want to look at using MVVM and data-binding. Globally that means; put all your `Course` objects into a collection, preferably a `ObservableCollection`. Then set the `CollectionView.ItemsSource` to that collection.

You won't need the `x:Name` attributes, instead the `{Binding MemberName}` will be used to fill the right values. I see you are already using that so that is great.

Comment: I am not using MVVM for two reasons: it needlessly complicates the code, and the course specifically excludes MVVM from the requirements. Is there a way to use the `ObservableCollection` without using MVVM? The Udemy course that I've used for the basis of this project doesn't include the `ObservableCollection` items until starting MVVM. Additionally, if I use `ListView` instead of `CollectionView`, these `x:Name` fields work without issues, but I can't get the list to appear the way I want it, which is why I switched to `CollectionView`.

Comment: I respectfully disagree that it needlessly complicates code, I think the amount of code will be the same, just different. Even less, since you don't need to set all values of a control explicitly. But I guess that's a matter of taste.

As for the rest. This worked in a `ListView`? I highly doubt that, you were probably doing something different. AFAIK it is just impossible to reach the `x:Name` controls by that actual name within a template.